# Javascript: Convert a UTC Date() object to the local timezone

Tags: javascript, date, time, utc

I have a `Date()` object that contains a UTC date, which I need converted to the users local timezone. Does anybody know how I could do this? :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually create a new `Date` object and use the `Date.setUTC*` functions to copy the date information.

Comment: There is a script that searches the page for dates formatted as a date microformat and replaces them with user's local version: http://features.sheep.art.pl/LocalTimeAndDate

Comment: Thanks, if you look at the javascript at the bottom of http://twtm.in/lw you'll see what I ended up doing :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure it is done for you automatically.

```
>>> d = new Date('Fri, 10 Jun 2011 19:49:23 UTC');
Sat Jun 11 2011 07:49:23 GMT+1200 (New Zealand Standard Time)
>>> d.getHours();
7
```

Comment: Yes, but the parse method works differently from browser to browser as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but just in case anyone else stumbles across this issue, here's how I got around this problem.

[UTC dates from ASP.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194016/how-to-get-current-user-timezone-in-c-sharp/30503614#30503614)

In my example, I wanted my ASP.Net service to return dates in the user's local timezone, even though the date values were stored in SQL Server in the UTC timezone.

Answer (score 0):

I found this for you:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC

The way you use it is:
    var x = Date.UTC(yyyy, mangmo, dd, hh, mi, ss, ms);
    // now x is a timestamp in milliseconds (it's a number, not a Date object)
    var y = new Date(x);
    // now y is the Date object you said you wanted
Arguments to `Date.UTC` are as follows:
`yyyy` is the year (for example, `1984` or `2016`)
`mangmo` is the **mangled** month (a number from **0 to 11**)
`dd` is the day of the month (this isn't mangled, it's the same as on a wristwatch or wall calendar)
`hh` is the hour of the day (0 to 23)
`mi` is minutes, `ss` is seconds, `ms` is milliseconds (I don't think I need to explain these)