# Get Local TimeZoneInfo

Tags: c#

I am using C#.  I need to get the local time zone info for the person running a web application.

I was wondering if:

```cs
TimeZoneInfo tzinfo = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(result.DueDate.Value, tzinfo);
```

is appropriate. Again depending on what time zone the person running the application is, I would like that to be reflected.

Comment: You said "web application" - are you trying to get the time zone of the *server* or the *client*?

Comment: I am trying to get the timezone of the client.

Comment: Here's how I convert a UTC DateTime into a user's local time for a website. The trick is to get the user (client) to tell the server which timezone they're in, and let the server offset the UTC DateTime into their local time:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194016/how-to-get-current-user-timezone-in-c-sharp/30503614#30503614

Answer (score 39, accepted):

yes you are right, this is what you should use. Alternative can be

```
TimeZone localZone = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;
```

but the `CurrentTimeZone` property corresponds to the `TimeZoneInfo.Local` property so no difference really.

it displays the names for standard time and daylight saving time for the local time zone.

Comment: You may want to clarify that this returns the local time zone of the machine hosting the process and not necessarily the "person who is running the web application".

Comment: Thanks. I am using TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc on the edited vesion above. Please let me know if this is the best approach. Thank you.

Comment: you want cliens time zone info or server?

Comment: I need to get the user's time zone.. So it will NOT be the time zone on the server. Please advise. Thanks

Comment: it won't be possible without javascript, see http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/vendettamit/setting-your-website-datetime-according-to-time-zone-offset-of-the-client/

Comment: @NatePet You need to unmark this as the answer. You asked if this will give you a web client's timezone and this answer says, "yes", which is incorrect. This code gives you the web server's time zone.

Comment: TimeZone is not the same as TimeZoneInfo so although one could argue that CurrentTimeZone 'corresponds' to the TimeZoneInfo.Local, there is a difference.

Regardless, the only way to get the timeZone on the client is for the client to post it to you explicitly. The link from Ehsan provides good info.

Comment: Why is this answer marked as correct answer? It doesn't provide the timezone of person running the application but the server where your website/app is hosted.

Comment: Yes, Why the answer marked as correct answer? It's giving the server machine timezone.

Comment: From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezone.currenttimezone), prefer `TimeZoneInfo.Local` over `TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone`. It states the reason.