# TimeZone Conversion for different Region

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012

Current Scenario.

DB server is deployed in US.

Application is deployed in Africa.
(Application fetches data-time from DB server which is in UTC and convert to local time zone which is Africa).

Client is using this application through browser in India.
(when client uses this application than it sees time that is of Africa through out application)

How to handle this so that client in India can see its local time instead of application time(Africa)????

Answer (score 1):

this may help: [How to get current user timezone in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194016)

The important function here is `new Date().getTimezoneOffset();`