# Converting UTC DateTime to Local DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I want to show Date & Time of an event which will be managed according to time zone of user. To check time zone I change my system time Zone to another time zone but my code is still getting Local time Zone.
Here's My code

I am using Cassendra Database and C# .NET MVC

```
DateTime startTimeFormate = x.Startdate;
DateTime endTimeFormate = x.Enddate;
TimeZone zone = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;
DateTime startTime = zone.ToLocalTime(startTimeFormate);
DateTime endTime = zone.ToLocalTime(endTimeFormate);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get current user timezone in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194016/how-to-get-current-user-timezone-in-c-sharp)

Comment: If you care about timezones use `DateTimeOffset` at least, not `DateTime`. As for your issue, what's the `DateTimeKind` value for `x.StartDate` and `x.EndDate`? Local, UTC or Unspecified? `ToLocalTime` only makes sense when you want to convert UTC to local. In the other cases, the only logical result is to return the same datetime value with a `DateTimeKind` of `Local`.

Comment: If the values come from the database, they are probably `Unspecified` as the database provider has no idea what kind of date they represent, or which offset to use.

Comment: Finally, to convert `DateTime` values from one timezone to another, use [TimezoneInfo.ConvertTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttime?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_TimeZoneInfo_ConvertTime_System_DateTime_System_TimeZoneInfo_)

Answer (score 13):

To convert the `UTC DateTime` to your `Local DateTime`, you have to use `TimeZoneInfo` as follows:

```
DateTime startTimeFormate = x.Startdate; // This  is utc date time
TimeZoneInfo systemTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
DateTime localDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(startTimeFormate, systemTimeZone);
```

Moreover if you want to convert `UTC DateTime` to user specific `Local DateTime` then do as follows:

```
string userTimeZoneId = "New Zealand Standard Time";
TimeZoneInfo nzTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(userTimeZoneId);
DateTime userLocalDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcDateTime, userTimeZoneId);
```

Note: `TimeZone` in `.NET` is [obsolete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezone?view=netframework-4.7.2) now  and it has been deprecated. Instead use `TimeZoneInfo`.

Answer (score 2):

`TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone`, `TimeZoneInfo.Local` and `ToLocalTime` use the local time zone of the *server*, not the end-user.

Instead, first see [how to reliably get the end-users's time zone in your .NET code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54406558/634824).

Then, assuming you now have a `TimeZoneInfo` object, simply use the `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc` method.

Answer (score 1):

These are DateTime helpers i use and that cover all of the cases i needed so far.

```
public static class DateTimeHelpers
  {
    public static DateTime ConvertToUTC(DateTime dateTimeToConvert, string sourceZoneIdentifier)
    {
      TimeZoneInfo sourceTZ = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(sourceZoneIdentifier);
      TimeZoneInfo destinationTZ = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("UTC");

      return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dateTimeToConvert, sourceTZ, destinationTZ);
    }

    public static DateTime ConvertToTimezone(DateTime utcDateTime, string destinationZoneIdentifier)
    {
      TimeZoneInfo sourceTZ = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("UTC");
      TimeZoneInfo destinazionTZ = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(destinationZoneIdentifier);

      return DateTime.SpecifyKind(TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(utcDateTime, sourceTZ, destinazionTZ), DateTimeKind.Local);
    }

    public static DateTime GetCurrentDateTimeInZone(string destinationZoneIdentifier)
    {
      TimeZoneInfo sourceTZ = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("UTC");
      TimeZoneInfo destinazionTZ = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(destinationZoneIdentifier);

      return DateTime.SpecifyKind(TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.UtcNow, sourceTZ, destinazionTZ), DateTimeKind.Local);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN documentation of the TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.timezone.currenttimezone), the local time zone is cached after the first call to TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone. In practice, this means your code should run fine as long as dynamic updates of time zone mid-run should not be supported. In order to see the changes immediately, before calling `TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone` you should call

```
TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData();
```

This is documented in the MSDN article as follows:

> Notes to Callers
>
> Local time zone data is cached after CurrentTimeZone is first used to
>   retrieve time zone information. If the system's local time zone
>   subsequently changes, the CurrentTimeZone property does not reflect
>   this change. If you need to handle time zone changes while your
>   application is running, use the TimeZoneInfo class and call its
>   ClearCachedData() method.