# Best way to get current web visitor timezone in asp.net core Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, timezone, razor-pages

I have one web written in asp.net core Razor Pages and I need to get current web visitor timezone in PageModel code. Is there any nice way to do it? I saw some JS approaches, but I dislike JS.

Comment: Why do you dislike JS?

Comment: Also, I did a Googe search for `c# get user timezone` and I got About 816,000 results in 0.59 seconds. One of them that looks promising is this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194016/how-to-get-current-user-timezone-in-c-sharp

Comment: The "best" way is to ask the visitor

Comment: The dup question is worth reading, but be wary of the current top-voted answer. It's wrong.  For the correct solution, please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54406558/634824  Thanks.