# Parse.com date issues using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

I am build a simple task manager where a form has two input text fields of title and description and one date field using jquery datepicker. I have displayed my data in table and used parse.com as my backend to store and retrieve data.
My problem is when I set my date object using parse.js I face these problem i.e

```
 var sDate=new Date($(".date-task").val()); //Date {Tue Jun 26 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)}

var todo = new TodoList();

todo.set('dueon',sDate); // this is how I set the value in parse

todo.save();
```

But when I go to parse .com the date is saved to previous date ie Mon Jun 25 2012 18:30:00 GMT

when I check the post in firebug the date is posted as

```
 __type     "Date"

iso   "2012-06-25T18:30:00.000Z"
```

how do I save the correct date in data browser of parse.com

Comment: hey guys plz help,someone must have used parse.com using javascript

Answer (score 1):

The posted date is correct since "Tue Jun 26 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)" is the same as "Mon Jun 25 2012 18:30:00 GMT" and Parse uses [Unix timestamps](http://www.epochconverter.com/) which are in the GMT timezone.

Basically you just have to convert the date from GMT to your timezone (IST in this case). You can look [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741348/javascript-convert-a-utc-date-object-to-the-local-timezone) to see how it's done.

Comment: thnks for the reply. I have retrieved and  displayed the date properly in my view in IST from parse but how do I get IST date  in data browser of parse.com

Comment: I mean the created and updated date matches Tue Jun 26 2012 00:00:00 GMT

Comment: @Nitish: I don't know that since I haven't used that tool. Perhaps there is some sort of configuration that allows the user to set the timezone.